# account not approved yet Google AdMob

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob

I have created AdMob account 1 months ago, And I am trying to show ads on my APP. No errors on the app showing and no ads showing also. In the logcat I find message *"account not approved yet"*. Also I opened Ad inspector and same message found.

This what I did so far

- I changed the ad ids to testing one and ads works fine so no problem in the code
- I went to my AdMob account and tried to find any issue with my account

  Account status - open

  In Policy centre window I have this message

  ```
      No current issues
      You don't have any current issues that stop or limit ad serving in your apps. Keep up 
      the  good work!
  ```

  In Disapprove window I have this message

  ```
   No disapproved apps
   If you have apps that have been reviewed, but not approved yet, they'll appear here.
  ```
- Payment method is set

The only warning I got on my account is "Requires review" as I didn't publish my app yet and I choose the option not published when I created my APP .

Can Any one help why I am getting this message and why I cannot show ads?

Comment: Have your account been approved? How long you had to wait? I am asking because I am currently waiting for approval for 20 day... And start getting worried..

Answer (score 1):

Just wait it needs time, but also you can do some steps to enhance your chances of quickly review.

- Publish your app and [link app store or Google Play with AdMob](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/10037806?hl=en#zippy=)
- [Set up an app-ads.txt file for your app](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9363762?hl=en)
- Contact AdMob support (if you can, not everyone can contact support) and try to verify your identity. always use passport as identification